# How to express travel capability and its distance in CV?

Tags: resume, travel

I know the thread [Refusing to travel](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/35276/refusing-to-travel), but I need to express the travel capability in my resume/CV because often asked. I have no limits if costs are compensated and/or me informed enough early about the travel. 
Other part is how far. 
I am not against any country but have some wishes. 
My proposal

- I can travel worldwide but mostly around Nordic countries (Sweden/Norway/...) and Europe if costs are compensated.

Assume you have two cities (Tallinn and Stockholm) scheduled in your Calendar for the next one year in the ratio of 60 to 40. I think I should include both in my address field. Now, I have it like

> Tallinn, Estonia. Stockholm, Sweden.

OK. I reject this idea. I put to the address field my primary location (etc `Tallinn, Estonia`, just example here). 
In Experience, the reader can see my other location because of my work, so clarifying (etc `Stockholm, Sweden`). 
I still express explicitly that

> I am looking for new part-time opportunities, and I can be relocated.

Comment: Do you really mean that you're willing to travel around the Nordic countries *at your own expense* if your new employer wants you to?

Comment: @SimonB It of course depends because I am often in those countries. If too much travel, then of course, I am not going to compensate the things myself. This is the reason why I am having those countries explicitly there. - - It also depends which duties/tasks/... I can get. In good cases, can I easily compensate the travel costs myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in a comment on another answer you mention:

> I have two cities (Tallinn and Stockholm) scheduled in my Calendar for
>   the next one year in the ratio of 60 to 40. I think I should include
>   both in my address field. Now, I have it like Tallinn, Estonia.
>   Stockholm, Sweden. What do you think? - - To include only one city is
>   rough estimate. To include separate dates at each cities is too
>   cumbersome and should be left for the cover letter.

Your situation isn't standard. When people inquire about how much traveling a position requires they generally are talking about one of two things.

- how often will I have to stay in another city overnight, and how long will the typical trip be in terms of number of nights? It is assumed and expected that all transportation, lodging and food will be covered. There may also be other perks such as extra vacation days. The question is usually asked when the employee has certain obligations that can only be done in the home city: family, school...
- how often do I need to travel in the local region? these are day trips to meetings or customers. The amount of local travel and the typical locations can determine if a personal vehicle is needed, or one is provided, or if taxi/uber/public transportation will work. There is also an expectation for reimbursement.

You seem to be looking for either a job that will allow you to work remote or in multiple cities, or only part of the year in a specific city.

These are much harder to find. I wouldn't use the CV/resume to limit options. I would be only applying to positions where it appears there is the flexibility you desire.

Posting your CV with dates in each city on a job board will not work to only receive interest from places that meet your requirements. Many of the companies or recruiters will be scanning the words you write to see if you meet the minimum qualifications, they will either ignore your schedule, or decide it is not worth the effort to understand what you want to accomplish.

Use your resume/CV to convince them they should hire you. Don't use it give them reasons to reject you.

Comment: Great explanation to the topic! - - Is worth to have a sentence `I can be relocated.` in the introduction of CV?

Answer (score 9):

I wouldn't put this information on the CV at all. If the job ad mentions "must be available to travel throughout Europe" you can mention in your cover letter that you are happy to do that. (Don't say "if costs are compensated", costs are always compensated and letting them know you aren't aware of that might make them think you are inexperienced and naïve.) If the job ad doesn't mention travel, willingness to travel is not going to be a factor in deciding who to interview, so there's no need to mention it.

At the interview, ask if there is any travel required and make sure you discover how far, how often, and what kind of conditions (drive your own car, fly, fly business class, ...) it entails. You might also ask how much notice you get about trips and how mandatory they are. There's a big difference between

> once a year we'll pay for you to attend some conference you want to attend, that you bring us and request.

and

> three or four times a quarter we'll send you on just a few days' notice to a small town in the middle of nowhere to solve a client's urgent problem. You have to go if we send you.

These nuances can't be covered by "I'm willing to travel a bit", so save the conversation for the interview.

Comment: Great arguments! Should you also explain the wish for the primary office location in CV? - - Etc `I am looking for new part-time opportunity in Norway, Sweden, Finland and/or England`.

Comment: Personally, I would not include a "broad" preference like that. If you are only willing to work in the city where you live, then saying that your objective is a _____ position in the city of ______ is ok, but not necessary. It's up to you to apply to jobs that meet your filters; don't put your filters in your CV and then apply to things that may or may not be ok for you.

Comment: I leave it like this `I am looking for new part-time opportunity`. I do not put my city because I do not want work there. I instead relocate myself regularly to other cities for project-like work. So I think leave it away. - - I am not sure if I should set filter to countries at all. I had those Nordic countries because I am from there.

Comment: I agree, except I wouldn't even bring it up at the interview, I'd cross that bridge when I need to, if ever.

Comment: @Kilisi you wouldn't bring up travel, or what city the job is in? I think both of those are pretty important topics for the interview. Absentmindedly taking a job that requires travel you're unwilling to do would be awful.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 - if the job is in a city that is different from your current location, I'd mention the job's city so that the interviewer is aware you are looking to relocate (or at least willing and able). Cover letters should always be tailored for the job you are applying to and, as an interviewer, I hesitate when I get generic looking cover letters from interstate.

Comment: @HorusKol I have two cities (Tallinn and Stockholm) scheduled in my Calendar for the next one year in the ratio of 60 to 40. I think I should include both in my address field. Now, I have it like `Tallinn, Estonia. Stockholm, Sweden.` What do you think? - - To include only one city is rough estimate. To include separate dates at each cities is too cumbersome and should be left for the cover letter.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 - this is a very different situation to what was implied in your original question... i think mhoran_psprep's answer pretty much covers things

Answer (score 4):

> How to express travel capability and its distance in CV?

This shouldn't go in your CV.

If there seem to be specific travel requirements associated with the job for which you are applying you can indicate your ability to meet those requirements in your cover letter.

Otherwise, if the subject comes up you can discuss your ability to travel during your interviews.

Comment: Yes, the CV is not the place to be limiting yourself.